# SparkSql Column shift issue

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am executing a Spark SQL query.

```
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT classification,
                    docType,
                    keywordList,
                    target_code
                    from psyc""").show(15)
```

I am getting weird results in a row where the columns are shown randomly. (fifth row from bottom). I checked the unique values in different columns in the CSV file and those columns doesn`t contain these values.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      classification|             docType|         keywordList|         target_code|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[{'code': '3297',...|     Journal Article|"['biochemical ma...|[1940, 5940, 5977...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['learning portfo...|[10330, 12810, 30...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['medical educati...|[11448, 16140, 30...|
|[{'code': '2227',...|     Journal Article|['medical communi...|[10540, 30340, 30...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['teaching course...|[30340, 40680, 46...|
|[{'code': '2224',...|     Journal Article|['outpatient clin...|[23340, 35970, 40...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['problem-based l...|[10140, 30340, 30...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['multifaceted ed...|[30340, 30350, 30...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['computer-aided ...|[23415, 30340, 30...|
|[{'code': '3410',...|     Journal Article|['professional ro...|[12810, 30340, 30...|
| either a confide...| all rights reser...|     Journal Article|['recognition mem...|
|[{'code': '2240',...|     Journal Article|['subjective prob...|[11230, 34420, 40...|
|[{'code': '2343',...|     Journal Article|['item recognitio...|[30570, 43350, 47...|
|[{'code': '2343',...|     Journal Article|['list length', '...|[20350, 30570, 39...|
|[{'code': '2340',...|     Journal Article|['Euclidean dista...|[30883, 43000, 48...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL ") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext                       
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

fp = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'psyc.csv')
df = spark.read.csv(fp,header=True)
df.printSchema()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("psyc")
```

[image]

Comment: your have issue with CSV file. if you will see there will be extra comma there where it is splitting incorrectly

Comment: Thanks @Nikk You were right. I have changed the delimiter to tabs.

Comment: Happy to help !!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common issue "Embedded delimter". The default delimter of spark sql ","   is also present inside the field.To avoid these issues 
1. we need to request and get proper files from our source systems
2. Else we have to do preproces the files to elimate those embedded delimited characters

Once we had this sort of issue for just 4 records out of ~300 million records